# How to add Toolbar as titleview?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to add UIToolbar as titleview for navigationitem. toolbar has been sucessfully added on titleview. but seems like frame is not getting set properly.

[image]

above is output I am currently getting. I am not setting right/left bar button.

Thanks.

Comment: "but seems like frame is not getting set properly." means what exactly. plz mention exactly what you want

Comment: what are the starting position of ur titleView

Comment: If you see the screenshot, there is patch on right and left side of navigation bar and border on the top side. from that I am saying it might be issue of frame. I am using sizeToFit for this.

Comment: frame positions of titleView?

Comment: Not setting frame of titleview, directly assigning toolbar as titleview. iToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];                                   [iToolBar sizeToFit];

Comment: then you want it full of navigation bar

Comment: try it .iToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectFrame:(-15,0,320,44)];

Comment: assign minus position to left side i.e. first parameter

Comment: looking for full of navigation bar.above frame is not working.

Comment: dont assign to titileView. add as subview to navigation bar

Answer (score -1):

instead of assigning to titleview, add it as a subview

```
[navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:toolBar];
```

if it not works then do like following

create one view like this

```
UIView *yourView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:navigationController.navigationBar.bounds];
yourView .backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[yourView addSubView:toolBar];
ctrl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:yourView];
```